# OAuth combined with custom users

Tags: oauth

I have a website where users can create an account and log in. This is stored in a database on the server. I also want users to be able to log in with Facebook etc, and thus skip the account creation. I don't know how to combine this and keep it persistent in the database. Any good examples on this use case?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first see how logins work in general. When a user is logging in for the first time, a session id is generated for the user and is stored in the browser of the user as a cookie *(note that there are mechanisms to store session id without a cookie, but let's assume you require a cookie for simplicity)*.

For subsequent requests to other pages in the same website, the cookie is also sent along. With this cookie (which has the session id), the unique user can be identified.

**So, all that you require to know to identify a user in the server side (upon a web request) is the session id.**

Having said that, if you want to include facebook etc into the login mechanisms, you need to do two things:

1. Connect your website with facebook (you will require a facebook developer account and some keys. Look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.0%29)). When you do this successfully, if the user selects facebook login, your website should redirect to facebook login page and once the user logs in into facebook account, facebook will redirect back to your website with a token. This token is an indication that the user is a 'real' user. If required, you can use the token to get more details (such as facebook id, email address, name, etc.) from APIs facebook.
2. The second step is the same for any authentication flow. You need to generate a session id for use by your server and then save the session id in cookie.

What I have specified is the general flow on how your requirement could be achieved. The mechanics of how to do this will depend on the server side technology that you are adopting (such as ASP.NET, Ruby, etc.)

Additionally, if your website requires storing information about the user behavior / user activity, you may need to additionally check if the user logged in via FB already exists in your database. If not present, you can store the user's facebook id or something to uniquely identify the user later. With this as the primary key / user id, you can store user activity (such as inserting a record in orders table if the user purchases a product).